# Determine a time interval

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I try to create in SSRS a chart which should show me only the Sunday at 10 pm until 11 pm value.

My query:

```
select intervaldateweek as Week,
       SUM(GoodUnits) As GoodUnits,
       SUM(NetUnits) As NetUnits,
       SUM(GoodUnits)  / NULLIF(SUM(NetUnits) , 0.0)* 100 As Value
from Count
    inner join tsystem ON Count.systemid = tsystem.ID
where IntervalDate >= getdate()-300
  and tsystem.ID = 2 
group by intervaldate
```

I tried it with this expression to get only Sunday:

```
(DATEPART(dw, IntervalDate) = 1
```

But I don´t know how am I can determine a specific time interval. In this case 10pm - 11pm.

I need the values between this time period

Between the hour of 22:00:00 to 23:00:00

```
 IntervalDate >= DATEADD(HOUR, 1,CAST(DATEADD(DAY,0, CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)) AS DATETIME))
    AND IntervalDate <= DATEADD(HOUR, 22, CAST(CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) AS DATETIME))
```

I tried it with this expression but I think I set the false numbvers in the expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `DATEPART` function ([documentation here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx)) to look at the relevant parts, like the hour of a date time value. For example:

```
SELECT 
    intervaldateweek AS [Week],
    SUM(GoodUnits) AS GoodUnits,
    SUM(NetUnits) AS NetUnits,
    SUM(GoodUnits) / NULLIF(SUM(NetUnits), 0.0)* 100 AS Value
FROM 
    [Count]
    INNER JOIN tsystem ON [Count].systemid = tsystem.ID
WHERE 
    DATEPART(WEEKDAY,intervaldate) = 1 /* See note about SET DATEFIRST */
    AND DATEPART(HOUR, intervaldate) = 22
    AND tsystem.ID = 2
GROUP BY
    intervaldateweek
```

NOTE: When using the `DATEPART(WEEKDAY, ...)` function, be sure to know your server configuration because sometimes Sunday will be 1 and other times Sunday will be 7. You can force it using for example `SET DATEFIRST 1` to make it predictable. Refer to this [MSDN link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181598.aspx) for details.

*PS: Your select statement groups by `intervaldate`, yet your column list uses `intervaldateweek` which won't work. I'm going to assume that the group by is intended to be `intervaldateweek`.*

Answer (score 0):

you can use following line..

```
DATEPART(dw,GETDATE()) = 1 AND CAST(GETDATE() AS TIME(0)) BETWEEN CAST('22:00:00' AS TIME(0)) AND CAST('23:00:00' AS TIME(0))
```

no need to use that kind of things.

Comment: did you replace the GETDATE

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 select intervaldateweek as Week,
   SUM(GoodUnits) As GoodUnits,
   SUM(NetUnits) As NetUnits,
   SUM(GoodUnits)  / NULLIF(SUM(NetUnits) , 0.0)* 100 As Value
from Count
inner join tsystem ON Count.systemid = tsystem.ID
where DATEPART(dw,intervaldate) = 1 AND CAST(intervaldate AS TIME(0))
BETWEEN CAST('22:00:00' AS TIME(0)) AND CAST('23:00:00' AS TIME(0))
and tsystem.ID = 2
group by intervaldate
```

Comment: the date is saved in the database like this here: "2016-02-22 22:00:00.000"

Comment: what is the version you used?